# Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *"

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have found many solutions to various situations with "refused to xyz" due to Content-Security-Policy Settings.

However I can't seem to find what might be wrong if `''` gets refused.

The literal error message in the browser is

```
Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *".
```

It only happens in Chrome. Loading the page in Firefox or Internet Explorer works just fine.

I set the following CSP(this is really one line. I put new lines in for readability):

```
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
img-src 'self' data:;
frame-src 'self' *;
object-src 'none';
font-src 'self' data:;
```

Now it was my understanding that `*` means "everything". What is it that Chrome is showing me no love for?

Sidenote:
We have evaluated getting rid of `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` but we cannot at the moment. If this might be causing my problem please point out how. Otherwise I am aware that it's a security implication and we're workin on getting rid of it. For now it's here to stay.

Setting:
The webserver is an Apache:

```
# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64
```

**edit1**
The error occurs when trying to open the client's mail program from within the website. The user clicks on a link and the mail program is supposed to open.

This might be why Chrome displays an empty string (`''`) as the blocked content.

Comment: Our frontend department has found a workaround but I am not sure what the workaround was. If someone can shine some light on the issue though I'd be more than happy to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Had exactly that problem today.
I solved it by using

```
frame-src data:
```

Btw. '*' is only a wildcard for urls. data: 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' have to be added individually.

Comment: I am getting a similar error:  Refused to frame 'https://embed.windy.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' http://mesowest.utah.edu".  I am not sure the fix I need to put in my .htaccess file

Comment: I wasn't able to test this, but if people are testing it, pls give feedback. If it helps you I'll gladly mark it as the answer.